# how to create each list with different name whenever user click a button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to generate like this whenever user click..

```
ValueNotifier<List<Gettingfoldernotes>> addfoldernotesnotifier =
ValueNotifier([]);
```

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier1 =
ValueNotifier([]);

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier2 =
ValueNotifier([]);

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier3 =
ValueNotifier([]);

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier4 =
ValueNotifier([]);

ValueNotifier<List> addfoldernotesnotifier5 =
ValueNotifier([]);

Comment: Hello Akshay, could you please add more detail to your request? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you generating the result as a String or as code? Could you please add more context to your question?

Comment: generating the result as as code